# Speed up php web scraping

Tags: php, curl, simple-html-dom

Currently I am scraping using file_get_html() along with simple HTML dom from 10 different websites. The process is divided into two sections. In the first section I scrap the links to product pages and save them into MySQL database. Then run another script which gets links from the database and scraps data from them to save to another table in database.

In order to avoid timeout I query for 10 links at a time. Process them and save them before starting with the rest.

I want to speed up the process of data collection and want to know what are the best methods available to do so. Keeping in mind that I wouldn't want the foreign website to block me thinking I am executing some kind of attack by sending too much requests simultaneously.

```
$query = $database->query("SELECT * FROM links WHERE web='hoobly' LIMIT 10");
while ($array = $database->fetch_array($query)) {
    $slink = $array['link'];
    $html = file_get_html($slink);
    $html->find('blah blah');
}
```

Comment: curl, curl_multi. then of course, more bandwidth, faster cpu, more memory and better code that we can of course not see

Comment: You think using curl or curl_multi can improve the speed of the process as opposed to using file_get_html?

Comment: Is this a part of a web application that you wrote ? I mean, you need to this via browser ? If no, you can run this using the php CLI executable and let it run as much time as you want, and if you want to free your terminal and let the process run in background, you could fork it and call the next script to do the rest of the job.

Comment: No don't need it via a browser. Currently I have scheduled tasks running in the background. Can you shed some light on php CLI executable? Is there some document you can recommend reading which I can learn more about it?

Comment: "Currently I have scheduled tasks running in the background." just make sure you call them from th command line 'php myfile.php'

Comment: @nogad Thanks. I will try that. But that won't necessarily speed up the process right? Because when I run using window's task scheduler I am sure it is already running using something very similar. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Secondly has anyone used Rolling Curl? I was searching for curl_multi as recommended by @nogad and landed on this https://github.com/joshfraser/rolling-curl

Comment: task scheduler is going to run what you tell it to - want to do this faster - stop using windows its terrible at multitasking

Comment: @nogad unfortunately don't have an option other than windows at the moment. Can you kindly refer to some good curl_multi tutorial? or maybe some nice code in the answer?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138777/discussion-between-saad-bashir-and-nogad).

Comment: Unfortunately this link doesn't provide information on what methods to use along with curl_multi to reduce the load on CPU. Things like usleep or curl_multi_select

Comment: Is the bottleneck really your cpu? Please show some code.